# How do I print a message when the user installs my Python package using pip?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, setuptools

When my package is installed, with

```
pip install my_package
```

I would like to print a message to the console (e.g. informing the user about an important reorganization of my package). Is there a way to do this?

Simply putting a `print` statement in `setup.py` seems to have no effect, and I can't find any arguments to `setup` that are seem applicable.

How do I print a message to the console when the user install my Python package using `pip`?